# How to serialize a list and write the same to a txt file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

a Python newbie here.
Im learning Python and stuck at the below problem. I want my output file to be serialized. Please help.

```
#say the list is l = ['h','e','l','l','o']
filename = input("Input File name: ")
with open(filename+".txt",'w') as f:
    for items in l:
        f.write(f"{items}\n")
```

How do I add serial numbers to my output. I know to enumerate but how to add enumerate to the output file.

Comment: what do you mean by add serial numbers to my output? can you show the expected output?

Comment: @Y Temp - Your code already writes to a file, so why do you ask _how to write to a file_?

Comment: What do you mean by "serialize"? That has a different meaning in the context of programming than I think you are using

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['h','e','l','l','o']
filename = input("Input File name: ")
with open(filename+".txt",'w') as f:
    for index,items in enumerate(l,1):
        f.write(f"{index} {items}\n")
```

In enumerate first parameter is the iterable that is l and second parameter is from where you want to start your index

Answer (score 0):

Just do this :-

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    f.write(f'{i+1}.{l[i]}\n')        #l here is your list
```

Comment: Learned something new. Thanks for this Ritik.